# Is there any missable/locked out content at any point?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Is there any content in this game that is easy to miss, or locked out at any point in time? It's a fairly long game, with no new game+ (yet), so knowing what might be missed would help a lot going through the game the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Titan that houses Indol will become inaccessible at some point.

When:

> During the climb of the world tree, some time between chapter 8 and 9, Indol will become hostile. You will no longer be able to go back to Indol.

All other content should be obtainable at any point in time.